# Possible errors after removing python3.6 from Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: command-line, python, dpkg, bashrc

I have installed python3.6 in Ubuntu 16.04, but due to this my terminal was not opening so I fixed by removing python3.6. But I have run tons of commands in xterm to fix it. So by running it, I have also make changes in ./bashrc and dpkg, so for no further problem in my system. I want to fix my dpkg and bashrc files.please tell me way to restore my bashrc files and dpkg files.

After this when I run ipython notebook on terminal.

This gives me error of:

```
[0620/030433.630682:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!

Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly.
```

So I want to fix my bashrc and dpkg files

**Commands run by me**

Firstly I have run these commands after pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>:

```bsh
cd /usr/bin
sudo apt-get purge python3
sudo rm python3
sudo ln -s python3.5 python3
```

Then I pressed <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd> to come back to the desktop again.

**Then this does not work.**

Then to get back my genome terminal I have run these commands:

```bsh
cp ~/.bashrc ~/Documents/.bashrc.bak
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/**
```

It also does not work.

So I have run the command:

```bsh
sudo update-alternatives --config python3
```

and changed it to python 3.5 and uninstalled python 3.6.

So I want to fix my bashrc and dpkg files so that sandbox error can be solved.